# How to filter "permalink" from stream table on my wall?

Tags: facebook-fql

I want to filter and get "permalink" from my wall. To get the permalink I use the following query:

```
SELECT permalink FROM stream where source_id = me() and type != 80 LIMIT 0, 100000
```

I want the posts of my friends on my wall alone except the photos; I mean I need only the status and comments of my friends over my wall. using the "type" like,

```
SELECT permalink FROM stream where source_id = me() WHERE type IN (8, 46, 56)
```

was not at all helped me. Please advice. Thanks in advance.